# iTunes keeps starting automatically

Tags: itunes, macos

With 10.9 iTunes keeps starting automatically after few minutes and I don’t know why. I quit it and 3 minutes later, its starts again.

The problem persist after reboots.

This lines show up in the console after a reboot

```
01.02.14 00:49:49,820 iTunes[4107]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_WRITE] delete: "No such file or directory" - 0x2
01.02.14 00:50:29,773 com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[149]: (com.apple.iTunesHelper.108624[403]) Exited with code: 1
01.02.14 00:52:44,576 iTunes[422]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
01.02.14 00:53:11,817 iTunes[422]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:1
01.02.14 00:53:11,817 iTunes[422]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:1
01.02.14 00:53:11,817 iTunes[422]: tid:a203 - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
01.02.14 00:53:11,817 iTunes[422]: tid:a203 - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
```

another time, iTunes started automatically

```
03.02.14 21:10:47,390 iTunes[4752]: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:1
03.02.14 21:10:47,395 iTunes[4752]: tid:3903 - unable to query device capabilities
03.02.14 21:10:52,436 iTunes[4752]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
03.02.14 21:11:20,616 iTunes[4752]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:2
03.02.14 21:11:20,616 iTunes[4752]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:2
03.02.14 21:11:20,616 iTunes[4752]: tid:3a03 - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
03.02.14 21:11:20,616 iTunes[4752]: tid:3a03 - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
```

a third time today, this happens

```
03.02.14 22:10:54,381 iTunes[18608]: Entered:_AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected, mux-device:1
03.02.14 22:10:54,385 iTunes[18608]: tid:3107 - unable to query device capabilities
03.02.14 22:10:58,344 iTunes[18608]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue
03.02.14 22:11:27,051 iTunes[18608]: Entered:_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:3
03.02.14 22:11:27,051 iTunes[18608]: Entered:__thr_AMMuxedDeviceDisconnected, mux-device:3
03.02.14 22:11:27,051 iTunes[18608]: tid:14807 - Mux ID not found in mapping dictionary
03.02.14 22:11:27,051 iTunes[18608]: tid:14807 - Can't handle disconnect with invalid ecid
```

The following suggestions I already tried out

- iTunes really quits and gets a new PID
- no iOS device or iPod is connected
- I checked `/Users/username/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/`
  and`/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/`, there are no Plug-ins
  installed
- I checked launchd, but I’m not entirely sure, what I’m looking for
- iTunes is not set as a login item
- no mic or speaker connected
- all iOS devices have Wi-Fi sync deactivated
- infrared is disabled

  launchctl list

launchctl list

```
PID Status  Label
7756    -   0x7f9b8a417e90.anonymous.launchctl
7732    -   0x7f9b8a50d950.anonymous.zsh
7731    -   0x7f9b8a50d170.anonymous.login
7728    -   0x7f9b8a411c40.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7727    -   0x7f9b8a50d6a0.anonymous.com.apple.qtkit
-   0   com.apple.serveralertproxy
7702    -   com.apple.Server.v3.5488
7672    -   0x7f9b8a50cec0.anonymous.IMServicePlugIn
7668    -   com.jitouch.Jitouch.62512
7586    -   0x7f9b8a50cc10.anonymous.com.apple.hiser
7580    -   0x7f9b8a418500.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7578    -   0x7f9b8a50a760.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7576    -   0x7f9b8a50c1e0.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7528    -   0x7f9b8a50bf30.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7444    -   0x7f9b8a50c960.anonymous.AppleMobileDevi
7208    -   0x7f9b8a50bc80.anonymous.com.apple.Media
7108    -   [0x0-0x408408].com.smileonmymac.textexpander.helper
7106    -   com.smileonmymac.textexpander.51600
7095    -   0x7f9b8a417be0.anonymous.com.apple.hiser
7089    -   com.apple.iCal.26432
7088    -   0x7f9b8a50b630.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7087    -   0x7f9b8a626550.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
7084    -   com.apple.mail.37520
6835    -   [0x0-0x3d83d8].com.omnigroup.OmniOutlinerPro.MacAppStore
6735    -   com.apple.iTunes.34704
18  -   0x7f9b8a415570.anonymous.configd
6330    -   0x7f9b8a416020.anonymous.com.apple.hiser
6177    -   0x7f9b8a509270.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
5596    -   0x7f9b8a50ae50.anonymous.VTDecoderXPCSer
5595    -   0x7f9b8a413ac0.anonymous.com.apple.audio
5594    -   0x7f9b8a50aba0.anonymous.com.apple.audio
5593    -   0x7f9b8a417010.anonymous.com.apple.qtkit
5526    -   com.tapbots.TweetbotMac.53008
692 -   0x7f9b8a711b20.anonymous.com.apple.Color
643 -   com.omnigroup.OmniFocus.MacAppStore.44912
642 -   0x7f9b8a624380.anonymous.com.apple.audio
641 -   0x7f9b8a50a250.anonymous.com.apple.audio
640 -   0x7f9b8a509ed0.anonymous.com.apple.qtkit
639 -   0x7f9b8a509640.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
503 -   0x7f9b8a509970.anonymous.com.apple.audio
502 -   0x7f9b8a627960.anonymous.com.apple.audio
480 -   com.apple.Terminal.9360
479 -   com.macromates.TextMate.preview.51776
473 -   com.apple.iChat.38576
469 -   0x7f9b8a626f20.anonymous.com.apple.Weath
464 -   com.webinhq.ReadKit.47904
428 -   at.obdev.LaunchBar.35936
401 -   [0x0-0x2f02f].com.apple.AppleSpell
377 -   com.apple.iTunesHelper.108624
348 -   0x7f9b8a4135a0.anonymous.com.apple.WebKi
345 -   com.apple.Safari.4784
332 -   com.apple.ImageCaptureExtension2.10416
261 -   com.apple.systemevents.21856
251 -   0x7f9b8a70eba0.anonymous.com.apple.dock.
243 -   com.noodlesoft.HazelHelper.62160
242 -   com.getdropbox.dropbox.181664
241 -   com.flexibits.fantastical.82752
240 -   com.mizage.direct.Divvy.30128
205 -   com.apple.photostream-agent
206 -   com.dayoneapp.dayone-agent
207 -   2BUA8C4S2C.com.agilebits.onepassword-osx-helper
208 -   com.github.GitHub.Conduit
104 -   0x7f9b8a623140.anonymous.WindowServer
-   0   org.openbsd.ssh-agent
-   0   com.apple.ZoomWindow
209 -   com.apple.wifi.WiFiKeychainProxy
-   0   com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent
-   0   com.apple.warmd_agent
-   0   com.apple.VoiceOver
-   0   com.apple.UserNotificationCenterAgent
201 -   com.apple.usernoted
158 -   com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua
4563    -   com.apple.USBAgent
-   0   com.apple.unmountassistant.useragent
-   0   com.apple.universalaccessd
-   0   com.apple.universalaccesscontrol
-   0   com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn
185 -   com.apple.ubd
-   0   com.apple.TMHelperAgent
-   0   com.apple.tiswitcher
-   0   com.apple.talagent
166 -   com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
-   0   com.apple.systemprofiler
-   0   com.apple.syncservices.uihandler
-   0   com.apple.syncservices.SyncServer
-   0   com.apple.SubmitDiagInfo
287 -   com.apple.storeagent
-   0   com.apple.storehelper
5520    -   com.apple.spindump_agent
-   0   com.apple.speech.synthesisserver
-   0   com.apple.speech.speechdatainstallerd
-   0   com.apple.speech.recognitionserver
-   0   com.apple.speech.feedbackservicesserver
-   0   com.apple.softwareupdate_notify_agent
194 -   com.apple.SocialPushAgent
210 -   com.apple.soagent
181 -   com.apple.sharingd
-   0   com.apple.ServiceManagement.LoginItems
-   0   com.apple.security.keychain-circle-notification
703 -   com.apple.security.DiskUnmountWatcher
-   0   com.apple.security.agentStub
-   0   com.apple.scrod
-   0   com.apple.screensharing.MessagesAgent
-   0   com.apple.screensharing.agent
-   0   com.apple.ScreenReaderUIServer
247 -   com.apple.scopedbookmarksagent.xpc
-   0   com.apple.SafariNotificationAgent
-   0   com.apple.safaridavclient
-   0   com.apple.ReportPanic
-   0   com.apple.ReportGPURestart
-   0   com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
-   0   com.apple.ReportCrash
-   0   com.apple.RemoteDesktop.agent
-   0   com.apple.reclaimspace
471 -   com.apple.recentsd
-   0   com.apple.rcd
-   0   com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper
-   0   com.apple.quicklook
-   0   com.apple.quicklook.config
-   0   com.apple.quicklook.32bit
-   0   com.apple.PubSub.Agent
-   0   com.apple.printuitool.agent
6838    -   com.apple.printtool.agent
-   0   com.apple.pictd
-   0   com.apple.PCIESlotCheck
285 -   com.apple.pbs
178 -   com.apple.pboard
-   0   com.apple.parentalcontrols.check
-   0   com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus
-   0   com.apple.nsnetworkd
213 -   com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent
-   0   com.apple.NetworkDiagnostics
-   0   com.apple.netauth.user.gui
-   0   com.apple.midiserver
-   0   com.apple.metadata.mdwrite
-   0   com.apple.mdmclient.cloudconfig.agent
-   0   com.apple.mdmclient.agent
-   0   com.apple.maspushagent
196 -   com.apple.Maps.mapspushd
-   0   com.apple.ManagedClient.agent
-   0   com.apple.lookupd
-   0   com.apple.locationmenu
183 -   com.apple.librariand
214 -   com.apple.LaunchServices.lsboxd
6174    -   com.apple.lateragent
-   0   com.apple.java.updateSharing
-   0   com.apple.java.InstallOnDemandAgent
-   0   com.apple.isst
-   0   com.apple.installd.user
-   0   com.apple.IMLoggingAgent
-   0   com.apple.imklaunchagent
216 -   com.apple.imagent
200 -   com.apple.identityservicesd
-   0   com.apple.icloud.AOSNotificationAgent
-   0   com.apple.icbaccountsd
7692    -   com.apple.helpd
197 -   com.apple.gamed
-   0   com.apple.FTCleanup
-   0   com.apple.FontWorker
-   0   com.apple.ATS.FontValidatorConduit
-   0   com.apple.ATS.FontValidator
-   0   com.apple.FontRegistryUIAgent
186 -   com.apple.fontd
-   0   com.apple.findmymacmessenger
167 -   com.apple.Finder
-   0   com.apple.FilesystemUI
-   0   com.apple.familycontrols.useragent
5978    -   com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert
-   0   com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand
164 -   com.apple.Dock.agent
-   0   com.apple.DiskArbitrationAgent
-   0   com.apple.DiagnosticReportCleanUpAgent
-   0   com.apple.csuseragent
-   0   com.apple.coreservices.uiagent
219 -   com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication
-   0   com.apple.CoreRAIDAgent
-   0   com.apple.CoreLocationAgent
-   0   com.apple.coredata.externalrecordswriter
7607    -   com.apple.cookied
-   0   com.apple.ContainerRepairAgent
-   0   com.apple.cmfsyncagent
-   0   com.apple.cfnetwork.cfnetworkagent
-   0   com.apple.cfnetwork.AuthBrokerAgent
192 -   com.apple.CalendarAgent
-   0   com.apple.btsa
375 -   com.apple.bookstoreagent
-   0   com.apple.bluetoothUIServer
-   0   com.apple.BezelUIServer
-   0   com.apple.avrcpAgent
-   0   com.apple.AssistiveControl
-   0   com.apple.assistantd
-   0   com.apple.assistant_service
-   0   com.apple.apsctl
-   0   com.apple.appstoreupdateagent
-   0   com.apple.appsleep
-   0   com.apple.AOSPushRelay
-   0   com.apple.aos.migrate
4782    -   com.apple.alf.useragent
7664    -   com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent
-   0   com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent
-   0   com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync
-   0   com.apple.AddressBook.AssistantService
-   0   com.apple.AddressBook.abd
199 -   com.apple.accountsd
-   2   jp.co.canon.UFR2.BackGrounder
-   2   jp.co.canon.CUPSCMFP.BackGrounder
-   0   com.google.keystone.system.agent
-   2   ws.agile.1PasswordAgent
-   0   com.valvesoftware.steamclean
-   0   com.shirtpocket.backuponmount
-   0   com.shirtpocket.backuponmount-login
71  -   0x7f9b8a500510.anonymous.loginwindow
-   0   com.apple.launchctl.Aqua
7466    -   0x7f9b8a417610.anonymous.com.apple.iClou
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.single.07000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
15  -   0x7f9b8a50b100.anonymous.securityd
6304    -   0x7f9b8a4172c0.anonymous.com.apple.geod
6253    -   0x7f9b8a416570.anonymous.com.apple.MailS
5986    -   0x7f9b8a506790.anonymous.com.apple.lakit
101 -   0x7f9b8a629ac0.anonymous.socketfilterfw
47  -   0x7f9b8a629810.anonymous.usbd
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail.03000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail.04000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
16  -   0x7f9b8a629120.anonymous.diskarbitration
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.32bit.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
577 -   0x7f9b8a628590.anonymous.com.apple.appst
498 -   0x7f9b8a414a20.anonymous.com.apple.Chara
403 -   0x7f9b8a505f80.anonymous.com.apple.Input
374 -   0x7f9b8a625f50.anonymous.com.apple.BKAge
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.single.08000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
7729    -   com.apple.mdworker.shared.04000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.shared.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
7730    -   com.apple.mdworker.shared.03000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
7711    -   com.apple.mdworker.shared.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
296 -   0x7f9b8a504160.anonymous.DataDetectorsDy
275 -   0x7f9b8a6233f0.anonymous.com.apple.Notes
255 -   0x7f9b8a70ee50.anonymous.com.apple.Share
238 -   0x7f9b8a501a50.anonymous.com.apple.IconS
234 -   0x7f9b8a40f990.anonymous.IMDPersistenceA
232 -   0x7f9b8a40f380.anonymous.com.apple.inter
89  -   0x7f9b8a500c70.anonymous.apsd
124 -   0x7f9b8a70d870.anonymous.CVMServer
104 -   0x7f9b8a40e850.anonymous.WindowServer
67  -   0x7f9b8a70d5d0.anonymous.mds
42  -   0x7f9b8a622990.anonymous.coreservicesd
71  -   0x7f9b8a40de90.anonymous.loginwindow
-   0   com.apple.xmigrationhelper.user
-   0   com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent
182 -   com.apple.tccd
7719    -   com.apple.syncdefaultsd
478 -   com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd
264 -   com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3
202 -   com.apple.secd
5979    -   com.apple.sbd
-   0   com.apple.pluginkit.pkd
-   0   com.apple.netauth.user.auth
378 -   com.apple.metadata.mdflagwriter
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.sizing
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.single
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.shared
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.mail
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.lsb
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.isolation
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.bundles
-   0   com.apple.mdworker.32bit
-   0   com.apple.mbpluginhost.user
-   0   com.apple.mbloginhelper.user
-   0   com.apple.KerberosHelper.LKDCHelper
-   0   com.apple.FileSyncAgent.PHD
159 -   com.apple.distnoted.xpc.agent
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_x86_64_1
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_x86_64
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_i386_1
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_i386
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64_1
7708    -   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_i386_1
-   0   com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_i386
162 -   com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent
-   0   com.apple.launchctl.Background
```

Comment: Do you have an iPhone or so attached?

Comment: no, no iPhone attached

Comment: I get the following error message in the console, when I quit iTunes.
15.11.13 22:56:54,059 iTunes[1104]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_WRITE] delete: "No such file or directory" - 0x2

Comment: Are you sure it really quits (new iTunes should have a new PID then)?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but do you have some sort of helper app running, that shows you what iTunes is playing in the menu bar (or somewhere comparable)?
These kinds of apps implicitly start iTunes, if they don't first check whether iTunes is running at all before asking it for the current song name.

Comment: Could you have something listed in launchd, what keeps iTunes restarting?

Comment: There seems to have been [similar problems](https://discussions.apple.com/message/5996397#5996397) when iTunes plugin iWow was used (they had to kill the process "genredetection" to solve the issue). Do you use any plugins?

Comment: with this message in the console, iTunes starts
18.11.13 16:03:29,562 iTunes[885]: ApplePushService: APSConnection being used without a delegate queue

Comment: Try repairing disk permissions in disk utility. It might fix things. After that, you could always delete and re-install iTunes.

Comment: I'm having this problem as well. I have not iDevices connected, no plugs installed, and not headphones plugged in.

Comment: I already repaired the disk permissions

Comment: I would try two things.

1, check if you have any plugins in  `/Users/username/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/`  or
`/Library/iTunes/iTunes Plug-ins/`  

if so quit iTunes and temporary move the plugins else where

2, try and see if this happens in another user account.

if you do not have a second user account to test with. Apple provide a web page with instructions of how to create a test user account

[How to troubleshoot OS X user accounts] http://support.apple.com/kb/TS4053

Comment: I deleted all iTunes Plus-ins folders, the problem persist

Comment: Try a reboot or logout. There maybe a launch agent still active. Also did you try another account

Comment: Also I found this thread https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2218516?start=30&tstart=0  a lot of people describing what you have and saying its the Jack from the speakers to the mac that is loose and acting like a remote..

Comment: There's a discussion right here about it : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1955511?start=30&tstart=0

Comment: What machine are you on - could you could update your question?

Comment: Sebastien, there have been a lot of suggestions. Could you edit your question and list the ones that you have tried, please.

Comment: 2 things. 1,  Open terminal.app which is in your /Applications/utilities folder. And run this command `launchctl list` This will list all the launch agents that are registered to run. post the result back here in you Question.  2, do you have speakers connected to the Mac. If so check they are firmly inserted. TSome reports if the connector is loose it can act as a remote.

Comment: I cannot see anything obvious in that list. maybe someone else would. You still not answered if you have speakers if so Have tested the Speaker cables as I suggested. The AMMuxedVersion2DeviceConnected (and I could be wrong) is implying some device is connecting. As I suggested if you have a speaker jack connected this could be the problem

Comment: @SebastianSemmler , Any feed back on the speakers from my last comment?

Comment: @SebastianSemmler is this solved? I just check something I spotted on a another thread. launchctl list only returns the users launch agents. sudo launchctl list returns all of them. my users counted to 280. using sudo returned 763

Comment: I've seen you have hazel installed. Are you sure it is not trying to import a file to iTunes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. It was one of third party Launchbar 5 Extensions. An Update von Launchbar 6 with the new extension fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you tell us how did the Launchbar 5 did that?

Answer (score 8):

`com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[149]` - looks to me like some process is using launchd as user 501 to open iTunesHelper. The PID in brackets is the culprit. What's process 149?

`launchctl list` will tell you what's loading via launchd. Check the list; if you see any plugins or helpers you know you removed, kill them with `launchctl remove name.of.process`

Two other things to try: You keep getting error messages about Mux IDs not existing. Kill all the items in the Mux ID list by deleting `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.usbmuxd.plist` and reboot.

If that doesn't help, trash iTunes and your iTunes plists, then download and install iTunes 11 fresh from Apple.

Comment: rebooting after deleting com.apple.usbmuxd.plist does not solve the problem. Which iTunes plists should I delete?

Comment: What's the anonymous.AppleMobile entry in your launchctl items? I checked my machine (running mavericks) and don't see that entry at all. If you are reinstalling iTunes just back up all plist files in /Library/Preferences and ~/Library/Preferences that contain iTunes in the name (compress to archive or copy to external media). Delete originals and iTunes app, then reinstall. If no change then safe to add back the original prefs. Really sorry that nothing seems to have helped so far, this must be infuriating to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

I've had problems with 3rd-party iTunes extensions not keeping up with iTunes updates and causing all kind of weird behavior.  In order to figure out if a plugin or extension might be involved, try starting iTunes up in safe mode:

http://support.apple.com/kb/ts3430

If the odd behavior goes away, then it's just a matter of figuring out which extension is the culprit.

Comment: no plugins are running

Answer (score 2):

I do know that an infrared remote can start iTunes if the "play" button is pushed.  Have you looked into this possibility?

To disable all infrared remotes, go to System Preferences -> Security and Privacy and click the "Advanced" button at the bottom of the window.  Then check the box labeled "Disable remote control infrared receiver".

To ensure only a specific remote that you trust and control is used with your computer, use the "Pair..." button in the same sheet, to pair your computer with a remote.

IF... you wanted to temporarily test this, without disabling anything, you could place a piece of electrical tape over the IR receiver on the front of your computer.  You know... just to make sure that nobody in the office is jacking with you.

Bill

Comment: I disabled infrared since always

Answer (score 1):

As well as turning off the infra red receiver I'd also plug in a pair of headphones which should cut down the possibility that it is something in the headphone jack. As I'm a total cynic I'd also replace your keyboard for the day.

See how those go.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it for me. The problem I had was that I was leaning on the integrated controls on the headphone cord for my AKG K619 set. Doh!

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem. This appeared to be an issue with the Last.fm scrobbler program for me. Force-quitting (via the apple menu) first Last.fm and then iTunes fixed iTunes rising from the dead again.

Answer (score 0):

I may have resolved a similar problem on a MacBook Air.

Nothing indicated here worked.

- Nothing was plugged into any port before or during experiencing
  thisproblem.
- I killed processes.
- I launchctl removed iTunes and it's helper.
- I removed the only Plug-In: Quartz
- I removed .plist files
- I rebooted. Repeatedly.

Rather than go insane, I expanded the iTunes package and trashed the two .apps.

Back in the console I noticed this message:

```
2/28/14 6:17:45.928 PM rcd[249]: spawn_via_launchd() failed, errno=22 label=com.apple.iTunes.25552 path=/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/MacOS/iTunes flags=1
```

This indicates that the remote control daemon is being triggered by a remote somewhere.

BUT MY MACBOOK AIR DOES NOT HAVE AN IR PORT!

So this is a bug or malware or a virus of some sort in my case.

This is how I stopped the problem, I used the [instructions of JeremyCrabTree to disable rcd](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2122639?start=210&tstart=0):

> The culprit here is the Remote Control Daemon, it lives in
>
> /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app
>
> To simply disable it, open a terminal window and type
>
> sudo chmod a-x /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
>   killall -9 rcd
>
> To re-enable it,
>
> sudo chmod a+x /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
>
> Then log out and back in. (I couldn't get iTunes to respond again
>   without logging out and back in)
>
> you will now be able to use your media keys with any app you want. You
>   won't be able to use them with iTunes, however. (odd, huh?) The
>   problem appears, to me, to be that rcd uses AppleScript to communicate
>   with the various Apple apps it controls (Quicktime Player, Quicktime
>   PlayerX, DVDPlayer, Aperture, iPhoto, iTunes, and Keynote) (warning
>   technical stuff to follow) If you view the strings contained in the
>   executable you can see it explicitly launching iTunes
>
> strings /System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd
>
> You will find the following, if you look for it,
>
> tell application id "com.apple.iTunes" to launch
>
> which is not present in the 10.5 version of rcd.app (yes, I checked)
>
> Just for giggles and grins I opened the executable
>   (/System/Library/CoreServices/rcd.app/Contents/MacOS/rcd) in a hex
>   editor and munged the launch command above. I logged out, then logged
>   back in. I can now use my media keys without autolaunching iTunes AND
>   I can still use them with iTunes when it is open.
>
> In summary, someone at Apple deliberately altered the Remote Control
>   Daemon to launch iTunes when using the play/pause button. It would be
>   trivially easy for them to fix, either by disabling it or making it a
>   configurable option.

Then I untrashed my two apps and went about my business.

I still don't know what caused it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing happen to me.  iTunes was automatically launching.  I finally figured out it was because of my bluetooth stereo speakers.  Every time I connected to my external bluetooth speakers, by either turning my bluetooth speakers on or turning my MacBook bluetooth on using the Menu bar icon control, iTunes launches.

So, at least now I know why iTunes is launching automatically.  It is because somehow iTunes is 'configured' to automatically launch when a bluetooth speaker of some sort becomes connected to my MacBook.

What I don't know is how to disable that behavior.

It seems kind of intrusive and disruptive that iTunes would 'assume' that every time I connect a bluetooth speaker I'm going to want to play music using iTunes.  I have not used iTunes for music in several years.  Maybe if iTunes/Apple had a decent streaming music service that was 1/2 as good as Spotify, I would, but I still would not want iTunes to ASSUME that I'm going to use it and launch itself.

I'll start iTunes when I WANT to use iTunes.  It is annoying that it is launching itself.  Apple thinks it knows better than I do when I want to use iTunes.  I THINK NOT.

If anyone figures this out, I would be very interested in knowing how to DISABLE iTunes from automatically launching based on when bluetooth devices are connected.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was relaunching immediately, so I had to quit iTunes while holding down command-option and held them down 'til it's inevitable relaunch. The dialog for iTunes safe mode came up, and iTunes launched. I quit iTunes. It didn't restart. I opened it again (not in safe mode) and quit and it doesn't relaunch anymore. Evidently, launching in safe mode forced some process to quit (maybe a visualizer?) that was causing the relaunch. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
In my case removing the earphone (it's a mobile earphone) solved the issue.
It seems when I plugin the earphone while playing some media files with either iTunes or VLC or anything for that matter the iTunes doesn't start automatically. But I think the point is to insert the plug in the jack only after when you have started playing (player doesn't matter).
If you insert the earphone before switching on the MBP or insert it just after logging in then the iTunes could pop up.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It turned out to be a Dashboard Widget. Try going to the Dashboard and remove any iTunes related widgets.

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost everything. It's probably hardware issue. The only thing that works for me is... log out user from iTunes when playing music from web.

Answer (score 0):

My iTunes was opening every time I'd make a Skype call to a telephone. Not only would it open, but it would cut off the outgoing sound so that the person I was calling couldn't hear me. I have a MacBook Pro. I tried a lot of things to get it to stop, including rebooting, to no avail. Finally I went to Finder>Applications and ctrl-clicked on the iTunes icon. Lo and behold, there were two Skype files in the Contents folder. I removed them and pasted them into the Skype Contents folder. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

When i have my headphone plug into my iMac, iTunes automatically start. In my situation, my iMac headphone plug slot is somehow broken. So my iTunes start randomly. I solved this issue simply by removing my headphone from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer: I have two speaker jacks in the back of my iMac.  One labeled for 'Headphones' and the other with a 'Pair of speakers' symbol.  I accidentally plugged my external speakers into the headphones jack.  When I switched to the other jack, the problem of automatic and repeated starting of iTunes stopped.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I had a Pimmsleur language CD in the CD player. So... it kept seeing a CD and turning iTunes on, playing whatever my last playlist was (weird). This happened randomly, it seemed to me, but especially if I was scrolling or start/stopping a Youtube video with my touchpad.

I like being able to leave a CD in, so, I went to my computer Settings, opened CD/DVD, and switched what to do with a CD in the slot from "Open iTunes" to "Ignore."

If I want the CD to open iTunes, I'll click on it and tell it to. Or just open iTunes.

So far, no more problems.

Answer (score -1):

UnCheck "Check for new software updates automatically" under "Preferences/Advanced"

Comment: Nope, that didn't work either! FUDGE!!

Answer (score -1):

https://blog.dave.io/2013/07/fix-for-itunes-starting-up-and-playing-music-by-itself-or-help-my-laptop-is-possessed/

This solved it here. I've just unplugged my headphone from the laptop. Never happened after it.

I hope that helps.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

On Yosemite- but this appears to not be release-dependent.  It is a "feature" not a bug.
I am experiencing this with a particular subprocess from a CNN webpage page in Firefox.  Never seen it before, but I thought it might be a server push request... sure enough, I close the page, and it stops, visit the url and it does it again.  I then disabled the Quicktime Firefox addon and reloaded the same url.  This prevented it trying to talk to iTunes.  I didn't see any code up-front in the HTML, so it was in some javascript includes it was using.  I'm not interested enough to dig around in the .js files to find it (it's bedtime).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem with Yosemite - in the end, it was quite simple.

Go to System Preferences > System > Users & Groups > [Your user ID] > Login Items.

The programs that automatically start on Login are listed.

If 'iTunes helper' is ticked, untick it.

Answer (score -2):

It appears that iTunes is set as one of your login items.

Go to system preferences>Users and select your account.

Towards the top of the window you will see a button labeled as "login items." Check iTunes(and any other unnecessary apps) and click the minus symbol to remove them from the list of apps that will automatically start.

If that doesn't help, you can try manually killing all iTunes-related tasks.

Comment: This doesn't explain the restart after quitting it though.

Comment: It’s not an login item, even the iTunes Helper isn’t a login item. As I said, I quit iTunes and a few minutes later it’s starts its self again.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. I just realized that, having headphones with a mike and a mute button, my elbow was accidentally pushing it. Stupid, for sure :-)